# Rails 3 - convert text_field data into the integer or decimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datamapper

In my `form_for` `text_field`I grab some numbers, which I need to compare in the controller, but that results's me wit an error -

> comparison of String with 0 failed

How can defind it as indeger or decimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `params[:your_text_field_name].to_i`